# return zero for no rows returned (in a complex query)

Tags: sql, oracle, coalesce

i am using following query in oracle. purpose of my query is to return zero if no rows are returned. otherwise i get 'no data found' error. i googled and came across coelese on stackoverflow.i used it as follows:-

```
SELECT COALESCE( (select sum(transaction_detail.amount)
from
    lookup_state , lookup_city , lookup_bank ,transaction_detail
where
   transaction_detail.bank_id = lookup_bank.bank_id
and
   lookup_bank.city_id = lookup_city.city_id
and
   lookup_city.state_id = lookup_state.state_id
and 
   lookup_state.state_id = 3 
group by
   lookup_state.state_name, lookup_state.state_id) , 0) into state_total_amount ;
```

i get following error:-

```
    from not present where expected
```

What am i doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you missed to write the `FROM` of the outer `SELECT`Statement.

Comment: Show us input and output. Are you trying to write a pl/sql block or just a query? provide us initial script (like, `create table ... insert into t ...`) or just a simple query with the section `with` (like, `with t as (...) select * from t...`). You will get your help much more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select coalesce(sum(transaction_detail.amount),0)
into state_total_amount
from
    lookup_state , lookup_city , lookup_bank ,transaction_detail
where
   transaction_detail.bank_id = lookup_bank.bank_id
and
   lookup_bank.city_id = lookup_city.city_id
and
   lookup_city.state_id = lookup_state.state_id
and 
   lookup_state.state_id = 3;
```